# Flutter Google Photo API fails randomly

Tags: flutter, dart, google-api, google-signin

Flutter Google Photo API fails randomly, I tried to logout and login several times.

There is the login flow working properly but whenever I call an API of google photo, it always fails with:

```
Unhandled Exception: Access was denied (www-authenticate header was: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/", error="invalid_token").
```

Answer (score 0):

I took me forever to resolve this. It turns out it is solved with a single line of code.

`await user?.clearAuthCache();`

For more context, this is error 401, and deep deep in the documentation , I found

```
 /// Clears any client side cache that might be holding invalid tokens.
  ///
  /// If client runs into 401 errors using a token, it is expected to call
  /// this method and grab `authHeaders` once again.
  Future<void> clearAuthCache() async
```

Very frustrating, I wish it refreshes the token automatically without listening to this status code on all my calls, I use this and ask the user to do it manually:

```
Future<void> handleSignOut() async {
    try {
      final user = await getUser();
      user?.clearAuthCache(); // added this line of code
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    await _googleSignIn.disconnect();
    client = null;
    currentUser = null;
  }
```